# Intentando entender el get_ticks()

Tags: python, pygame

Estoy haciendo un juego y he implementado colisiones, si la nave choca con un asteroide cambia a una imagen de una explosión.

Ahora me gustaría que después de chocar, la imagen de la explosion cambie en 2 segundos de vuelta a la imagen de la nave. He intentado entender el `get_ticks()` de `pygame` y sé que estoy cerca, pero algo se me escapa.

Os dejo el código por si veis algo mal. Muchas gracias de antemano.

```
def colision(self): #FIXME Añadir tiempo de colision
        '''Este metodo detecta las colisones que 
        se producen en la nave con los asteroides y resta vidas'''       
        self.colision_nave = pg.sprite.spritecollide(self.jugador, self.asteroides, False, pg.sprite.collide_circle)
        if self.colision_nave:
            self.momento_colision = pg.time.get_ticks()//1000
            self.jugador.nave_imagen = pg.image.load(os.path.join("resources", "images", "explosion.png"))
            print(f'Tiempo actual: {self.tiempo_actual} Momento de colision: {self.momento_colision}')
            if self.tiempo_actual - self.momento_colision < 2000:
                self.nave_imagen = pg.image.load(os.path.join("resources", "images", "Main_Ship.png"))
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Introducción

Primero que nada, voy a aclarar algunas cosas:

- Generalmente conviene cargar las imagenes antes de inciar el juego. Luego utilizas las imagenes ya cargadas (guardadas en variables o atributos) y el juego anda más rapido.
- No hay manera de que puedas en la misma función cambiar la imagen a la explosión y devolverlo a la normalidad sin que el juego se trabe y no muestre el cambio.
- La función `pygame.time.get_ticks()` contiene el tiempo pasado desde que se llamó a pygame.init. Edit: si sirve para eso, pero estarías trabajando con números cada vez más grandes...

Para crear un temporizador se puede seguir la siguiente logica.

- Establecer una variable en la cantidad de tiempo que debe pasar. En tu caso sería el tiempo que dura la imagen de la explosión en pantalla.
- Cada vez que el sprite se actualiza, le resto el tiempo que pasó (se puede usar pygame.time.Clock.get_tiks(), que devuelve el tiempo transcurrido entre dos llamadas a pygame.time.Clock.tick() en milisegundos. O sea, lo que duró el fotograma. O usar 1 para hacer la cuenta con fotogramas).
- Cuando el tiempo que guardé paso a ser >= 0, significa que ya paso el tiempo que había que esperar y hago la acción final (en este caso devolver la imagen a la normalidad).

#### Código

Para esto creé un "juego" muy basico que utiliza un objeto Timer (creado por mi) que se inicia cuando el jugador coloca el cursor sobre el sprite, lo que también cambia el color del sprite a verde. Cuando pasa el tiempo, el sprite vuelve a ser blanco.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys

# ------------------------------
# Clases y Funciones utilizadas
# ------------------------------

class Timer:
    def __init__(self, duration, function):
        self.duration = duration # aquí guardo la duración
        self.function = function # aquí guardo la función o método a ser llamado al pasar el tiempo
        self.is_active = False # aquí guardo si el temporizador está activado

    def start(self):
        self.time = self.duration # creamos una variable time que contendrá el tiempo restante
        self.is_active = True

    def update(self, dt):
        # Esto hace que se pueda llamar a timer.update(dt) en un temporizador inactivo
        # sin consecuencias. Es decir, no hace nada si el temporizador está "apagado".
        if(self.is_active):
            self.time -= dt

            if(self.time <= 0):
                self.is_active = False
                self.function()

class Sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((40,40))
        self.image.fill("white")

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.change_timer = Timer(1000, self.on_finish_change_timer) # esto está en milisegundos, si trabajas con fotogramas, la formula es fps * segundos que deben pasar.

    def on_finish_change_timer(self):
        self.image.fill("white")

    def update(self, dt):
        self.change_timer.update(dt) # actualizo el temporizador. Si está inactivo, no sucede nada.

        # si el temporizador está inactivo y el cursor está en el el rectangulo que contiene el sprite...
        if(not self.change_timer.is_active and self.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos())):
            self.image.fill("green")
            self.change_timer.start()

# ------------------------------
# Funcion principal del juego
# ------------------------------


def main():
    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    group = pygame.sprite.Group(Sprite())

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        dt = clock.get_time() # haz dt=1 si trabajas con fotogramas. La cantidad de fotogramas transcurridos siempre será 1 por razones obvias.

        group.draw(screen)
        group.update(dt)

        clock.tick(60)

        pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Podés usar el objeto timer para todo lo que necesites y mejorarlo si querés c:

#### Por que utilizar fotogramas

En lugar de pensar en el lapso de tiempo pasado podemos decir que pasen 60 fotogramas (redibujados y actualizaciones de sprites) por segundo, y asumir que cada fotograma dura lo mismo.
Esto tiene las siguientes ventajas:

- No requiere consultar el tiempo pasado.
- Si usamos tiempo normal y pasan un fotograma por segundo, en el juego transcurrirían un segundo sin que el jugador pueda hacer nada. Quizá perdió por que le explotaron la nave mientras no podía interactuar con el juego. En cambio, usando fotogramas, el juego avanzará un solo fotograma mientras al jugador le anda lag. Nota: no digo que tu juego vaya a andar mal, solo que, por ejemplo si creas un millon de naves, este se tardaría en actualizarlas a todas. Un programa es muy rapido, pero todo tiene su limite.

Esto en Pygame se logra usando un objeto pygame.time.Clock. A su función tick le pasamos la cantidad de fotogramas por segundo y Pygame hará todo el trabajo de ajustar la duración.